# C# Winforms: Is it possible to have a function in a form called from the main Program.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have this Exited event in my Program.cs where I have the main entry point for my application. It opens up another external program and monitors its status. If this external program closes, it needs to pop up a dialog box on the form that initially opens. I know how to capture the exited event but I need to call or run a function on another form with the action I want to perform.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void ExternalProgramFunction()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process startExternal = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("external.exe", String.Format(ConnectionArg));
        startExternal.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        startExternal.Exited += ExternalProgramExits;
    }

    public static void ExternalProgramExits(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserClose == false)
        {
            /// Need code here to open dialog box on another form!!!
        }
    }
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] arguments)
    {
        UserClose = false;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Manager());
```

I want this code to execute the following function that sits in another form. I am doing this so that the dialog box will open and keep the form from being able to be clicked. What I have listed below is some of my code from the other form. I want to run the prematureclosepopup from Program.cs

```
    public Manager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void PrematureClosePopup()
    {
        ManagerWarning messagepopup = new ManagerWarning();
        messagepopup.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep a reference to your `Manager` object:

```
static Manager _someClassMemberVariable;
```

Then change the last line in `Main()` to:

```
_someClassMemberVariable = new Manager();
Application.Run(_someClassMemberVariable);
```

Then you can change your `ExternalProgramExits()` method to:

```
public static void ExternalProgramExits(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UserClose == false)
    {
        _someClassMemberVariable.PrematureClosePopup();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking at this again and where do I put:
static Manager _someClassMemberVariable;
Under public static class Program or under static void Main(string[] arguments)??

Comment: As the top item in your `Program` class. Like the line above `public static void ExternalProgramFunction()`

Comment: Well, This all worked but sadly did not do what I was hoping it would do. Essentially I am trying to get the form called "manager" to open a dialog box so that the form CANNOT be clicked. I tried to put on Exited code in the forms code itself and it did not work well so I put my code to check the Exited state in the main program.cs. Anything you can think of would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidBentley That's going to be an issue with `ManagerWarning`. I'd have to see its definition.

Comment: `ManagerWarning` is just a regular Winform that I created.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is anything out of the box for what you are trying to do.  You could have your host application implement a TCP socket and then your other application you spawn up act as a TCP client and send a command and get a response whether they said yes or no.  This doesn't work if you don't have any control over the "external.exe" program though.

Comment: There's no 2 applications that need to talk to each other. All the OP is doing is calling a method on a form in the same application.